# Amazon IAM policy: restrict user to create group/role only if one of the attached policy is BaseDeny

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I wanted to restrict `IAM` user from creating new group/roles and allow only if user attaches custom policy `BaseDeny` along with other policies. Meaning there has to be `BaseDeny` policy in every group/roles created by user in order for him to create new group/roles.

I tried to add following policy to the user to achieve this, however this is allowing only `BaseDeny` to be added, but I wanted to allow if user adds any other policy along with `BaseDeny`.

What condition is needed to achieve this? Or any other way to make this work?

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [{
        "Sid": "ManageUsersPermission",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "iam:ChangePassword",
            "iam:CreateAccessKey",
            "iam:CreateLoginProfile",
            "iam:DeleteAccessKey",
            "iam:DeleteLoginProfile",
            "iam:UpdateAccessKey",
            "iam:ListAttachedUserPolicies",
            "iam:ListPolicies",
            "iam:ListUserPolicies",
            "iam:ListGroups",
            "iam:ListGroupsForUser",
            "iam:GetPolicy",
            "iam:GetAccountSummary",
            "iam:GetGroup",
            "iam:ListGroupPolicies"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "CreateGroupRoleLimited",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "iam:CreateGroup",
            "iam:AddUserToGroup",
            "iam:CreateRole",
            "iam:ListAttachedGroupPolicies",
            "iam:ListAttachedRolePolicies"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "AttachDettachLimitedPolicy",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "iam:AttachGroupPolicy",
            "iam:AttachRolePolicy",
            "iam:AttachUserPolicy"
        ],
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "ArnLike": {
                "iam:PolicyArn": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::*:policy/BaseDeny"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem have a look at [IAM Permissions Delegation](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/delegate-permission-management-to-developers-using-iam-permissions-boundaries/)

What you are trying to do is exactly what the delegation feature was built for. Instead of trying to make sure that a particular **BaseDeny** policy is included on new groups (one way to attempt to achieve a permissions boundary), follow the linked blog entry to create a permissions boundary that excludes what you wanted to deny with **BaseDeny**.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.

The closest option would be to create an [AWS Config rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/evaluate-config.html) to check for Roles/Groups that do not contain that policy.

This is checking "after-the-fact", but you could automate the rule to disable a Role/Group that violates the rule.

See: [How to develop custom AWS Config rules using the Rule Development Kit | AWS Management Tools Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/how-to-develop-custom-aws-config-rules-using-the-rule-development-kit/)